# running scheduled job in django app deployed on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have deployed a django app on heroku. So far it works fine. Now I have to schedule a task (its in the form of python script) once a day. The job would take the data from heroku database perform some calculations and post the results back in the database. I have looked at some solutions for this usually they are using rails in heroku. I am confused whether I should do it using the cron jobs extension available in django or using the scheduled jobs option in heroku. Since the application is using using heroku I thought of using that only but I dont get any help how to add python jobs in it. Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to create a Django management command for your project like `python mananage.py run_this_once_a_day`. And you can use Heroku schedular to trigger this scheduling.

Comment: I read in one of the questions that one should use django cron when there aren't external dependencies, my scheduling job imports a number of libraries will that affect when using cron?

Comment: I don't think so. See all the dependencies are readly available in heroku environmnet. I don't think any problem with that.

Comment: Hey i tried following your suggestion but turns out that heroku scheduler requires credit card entry, is that so? if yes is there any way around or other way?

Comment: No no other way around. But you can add your debit card as well. I added credit card and it's working fine. If you are in free plan you will not be billed. So no worries...

Comment: and can i add celery add on and then schedule the job?

Comment: yes I think but not sure. Please explore on your own